# Flair on Gmail Signature

Tags: feature-request

I put Flair on my Gmail Signature. I had to do it differently by adding a link to my profile then adding the image separately

Se image below for what it looks like.

Is there any issues with doing this??

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think what you have done is OK (and should be encouraged) but that is only my opinion, so I will instead refer you to the **[StackOverflow Meta discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120403/how-do-i-put-my-stack-exchange-flair-into-my-gmail-footer)** that has already taken place on this exact topic.